# C# | Memory Leak in windows service

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a Web API which is hosted as a windows service. There is a suspected memory leak in the application.

When looking at the task manager, with every HTTP request, there i a certain amount of memory which is held by the application.

Example. ON start of the service the process in task manager is at **5000K** memory, with first request the memory reaches to **40000K** and once processed it comes down to around **30000K**, with the next request onwards it increases from **30000K** to **60000K** and after processing comes down to around **45000K**.

When i monitored service using **perfmon**, all the graphs eventually came down, but the graphs for

> (#Gen 0 Collections, #Gen 1 Collections, #Gen 2 Collections)

are steadly increasing and never coming down.

Does **Gen 0,1,2 collections** holding the memory indicates memory leak in anyway.
[image]

I had a lot of referenced objects in the code, which i refactored and used a new instance of the objects. Will replacing the **Classes** with **Structs** help in this case. But as i understand Structs have instance size limits of 16 bytes, which won't work for me.

Comment: Replacing classes with structs won't fix the issue. Do you, by any chance, create a bunch of `string`'s in a loop? Or do you have any other loops which may cause this issue?

Comment: If you continue calling the service, do you ever get OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: Look at eventhandlers. Also, that structs have a max instance size if just wrong - they SHOULD be smaller than 16 bytes, but they MUSTN'T.

Comment: Does your application dispose all instances implementing IDisposable?

Comment: @codroipo i do get Out of Memory at some point close to 1.3 GB, since it's a 32bit application.

Comment: @Mafii because of policy restrictions i can't paste the code here, but my service has IDisposable implementation

Comment: Okay, do you use any events?